# DLNA Protocol: XML Tag for Cover Arts / Movie Posters?

Tags: xml, dlna, artwork

I am currently working on some kind of DNLA Media Server and want to make it possible to view Thumbnails and/or Artworks for movies etc. instead of default icons while browsing the available files. Now my question is what kind of XML Tags do i need to include in `<item>` to make it possible?

This is what I got so far:

```
    <item id="0$2$5$3" parentID="0$2$5" restricted="true">
        <dc:title>TestFile</dc:title>
        <res xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/" protocolInfo="http-get:*:video/avi:DLNA.ORG_OP=01" size="341663506" duration="00:23:44.00" resolution="1024x576" bitrate="245504" nrAudioChannels="2" sampleFrequency="48000">http://192.168.1.110:5001/get/0$2$5$3</res>
        <res protocolInfo="http-get:*:image/jpg:DLNA.ORG_PN=JPEG_TN;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=00f00000000000000000000000000000">http://192.168.1.110:5001/get/0$2$5$3/thumbnail</res>
        <upnp:albumArtURI xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/" dlna:profileID="JPEG_TN">http://192.168.1.110:5001/get/0$2$5$3/thumbnail</upnp:albumArtURI>
        <dc:date>2013-05-30T11:04:37</dc:date>
        <upnp:class>object.item.videoItem</upnp:class>
    </item>
```

As you can see I already use a second `<res>` and the `<upnp:albumArtURI>` Tags. On some devices this seems to work and the thumbnails are displayed. But on other devices it doesn't. Is this because of these devices not supporting thumbnails or is there something I forgot?

Answer (score 0):

`<upnp:albumArtURI>` and `<res protocolInfo..>` is all as far as I know.

There may be a chance that some device only accept `png`, and you may try to add `png` in `<res protocolInfo>`.